# iOS Crash Log Help Needed

Tags: ios, iphone, crash, crash-reports, symbolicatecrash

I've been receiving a few crash logs for a bug that I haven't been able to replicate. The crash occurs right when the user taps on a textView in the app. The textView is located under a tableView and I extend the bottom constraint of the textView to fit the keyboard on screen. The constraint extends through keyboard notifications (NSNotificationCenter keyboardWillShow).

Below are two crash logs. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x0000000189793014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x000000018985b450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x0000000189707400 abort + 140
3   libswiftCore.dylib            0x0000000100f55dbc swift_deletedMethodError (__hidden#18700_:282)
4   libswiftCore.dylib            0x0000000100f3b5e4 _hidden#18056_ (__hidden#18099_:392)
5   libswiftCore.dylib            0x0000000100f3b674 swift_dynamicCastClass (__hidden#18099_:478)
6   libswiftCore.dylib            0x0000000100f3b704 swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional (__hidden#18099_:502)
7   dotnative                     0x000000010029e4ac 0x100064000 + 2335916
8   dotnative                     0x0000000100290404 0x100064000 + 2278404
9   UIKit                         0x00000001907a8484 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1424
10  UIKit                         0x0000000190858f34 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 268
11  UIKit                         0x000000019090bfdc _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
12  UIKit                         0x00000001908fdd50 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 560
13  UIKit                         0x000000019066d0b4 _afterCACommitHandler + 168
14  CoreFoundation                0x000000018a7720c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15  CoreFoundation                0x000000018a76fcf0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
16  CoreFoundation                0x000000018a770180 __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
17  CoreFoundation                0x000000018a69e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
18  GraphicsServices              0x000000018c152198 GSEventRunModal + 180
19  UIKit                         0x00000001906e57fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
20  UIKit                         0x00000001906e0534 UIApplicationMain + 208
21  dotnative                     0x000000010006c9f4 0x100064000 + 35316
22  libdyld.dylib                 0x00000001896815b8 start + 4


Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000181c3f014 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000181d07450 pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000181bb3400 abort + 140
3   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100faddbc 0x100dd4000 + 1940924
4   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100f935e4 0x100dd4000 + 1832420
5   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100f93674 0x100dd4000 + 1832564
6   libswiftCore.dylib              0x0000000100f93704 0x100dd4000 + 1832708
7   dotnative                       0x000000010027a4ac 0x100040000 + 2335916
8   dotnative                       0x000000010026c404 0x100040000 + 2278404
9   UIKit                           0x0000000188c54484 -[UITableView _selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:notifyDelegate:] + 1424
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188d04f34 -[UITableView _userSelectRowAtPendingSelectionIndexPath:] + 268
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188db7fdc _runAfterCACommitDeferredBlocks + 292
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188da9d50 _cleanUpAfterCAFlushAndRunDeferredBlocks + 560
13  UIKit                           0x0000000188b190b4 _afterCACommitHandler + 168
14  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c1e0c0 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
15  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c1bcf0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 372
16  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182c1c180 __CFRunLoopRun + 1024
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182b4a2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
18  GraphicsServices                0x00000001845fe198 GSEventRunModal + 180
19  UIKit                           0x0000000188b917fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
20  UIKit                           0x0000000188b8c534 UIApplicationMain + 208
21  dotnative                       0x00000001000489f4 0x100040000 + 35316
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000181b2d5b8 start + 4
```

Comment: Would be better if we can see code in your class

Comment: I actually think it's been figure out. I was just being an idiot. Users were reporting crash on "textfield". They were actually referring to a cell that sorta looks like a textField. The cell was being miscast. Time to tweak the UI to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Users were reporting crash on "textfield". They were actually referring to a cell that sorta looks like a textField. The cell was being miscast. Careless mistake - will need to make UI clearer.