# Crashed: com.apple.main-thread log

Tags: ios, swift, crashlytics

I'm getting the below error from crashlytics and I'm having a really hard time trying to decipher it. I've tried to look into the `connectButtonTapped` method but don't see anything wrong at all. Maybe this isn't even where it's happening.. any ideas?

```
#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x180643014 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x18070b450 pthread_kill + 112
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x1805b7400 abort + 140
3  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100af3d1c swift_deletedMethodError (__hidden#19885_:285)
4  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100ad5e04 _hidden#19211_ (__hidden#19255_:184)
5  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100ad5e7c swift_dynamicCastClass (__hidden#19255_:270)
6  libswiftCore.dylib             0x100ad5f0c swift_dynamicCastClassUnconditional (__hidden#19255_:294)
7  TestApp.                          0x10010a464 specialized vcMeet.connectButtonTapped(sender : vMeetButtonSection) -> () (vcMeet.swift)
8  TestApp                           0x100107524 @objc vcMeet.connectButtonTapped(sender : vMeetButtonSection) -> () (vcMeet.swift)
9  TestApp                           0x1001075f4 protocol witness for vMeetButtonSectionResponderDelegate.connectButtonTapped(sender : vMeetButtonSection) -> () in conformance vcMeet (vcMeet.swift)
10 HighThere                      0x1001380c0 @objc vMeetButtonSection.connectTapped() -> () (vMeetButtonSection.swift)
11 UIKit                          0x18755fd30 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
12 UIKit                          0x18755fcb0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
13 UIKit                          0x18754a128 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 452
14 UIKit                          0x18755f59c -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 584
15 UIKit                          0x18755f0c4 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2484
16 UIKit                          0x18755a328 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 2988
17 UIKit                          0x18752ada0 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
18 UIKit                          0x187d1475c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2736
19 UIKit                          0x187d0e130 __handleEventQueue + 784
20 CoreFoundation                 0x181622b5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
21 CoreFoundation                 0x1816224a4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 524
22 CoreFoundation                 0x1816200a4 __CFRunLoopRun + 804
23 CoreFoundation                 0x18154e2b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 444
24 GraphicsServices               0x183002198 GSEventRunModal + 180
25 UIKit                          0x1875957fc -[UIApplication _run] + 684
26 UIKit                          0x187590534 UIApplicationMain + 208
27 TestApp                     0x10005a8b4 main (tbcSettings.swift:17)
28 libdispatch.dylib              0x1805315b8 (Missing)
```

Comment: Guess with reading `swift_dynamicCastClass()`, you casted an object, but it wasn't compatible. Same reason there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42710568/ios-crash-log-help-needed or there https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/68948

Comment: Turn on All Exception breakpoints, it may give you more information.

Comment: @WrightsCS where do I do this?

Comment: Looks to me like it is this: `vcMeet.connectButtonTapped(sender : vMeetButtonSection)` looks like the sender was not the correct type.

Comment: @chasenyc this can't be. I'm sending the object through a delegate like this `delegate?.connectButtonTapped(sender: self)` and i'm calling that in `vMeetButtonSection`. I have a questions, my delegate is labeled this way `weak var delegate: vMeetButtonSectionResponderDelegate?` and my protocol like this `protocol vMeetButtonSectionResponderDelegate: class` .. would this have anything to do with it?

Comment: Giving the code of `connectButtonTapped()` may help a lot. Else, the suggestion are all we can do, and according to the crash log, it seems to be a cast issue.